Contract bytecode generated by Hardhat is two times larger than generated by Foundry
I'm developing a contract using both hardhat and foundry. For some reason hardhat generates bytecode that is two times larger than the one generated in foundry. Why may it happen?
Source code:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

contract SizeTest {
    address public immutable owner;
    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
}

Foundry 0.2.0:
6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b506004361060285760003560e01c80638da5cb5b14602d575b600080fd5b60537f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000081565b6040516001600160a01b03909116815260200160405180910390f3fea26469706673582212207bf5089fc3128e2f0334465c3ed0fd8e1fc3b11be15a78a8e19d374e7403358664736f6c634300080a0033
Hardhat 2.20.1:
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
Foundry config:
[profile.default]
src = "contracts"
out = "out"
libs = ["lib"]
evm_version = 'paris'
optimizer = true
optimizer_runs = 200
solc_version = '0.8.10'
via_ir = false

Hardhat config:
  solidity: {
    settings: {
      metadata: {
        bytecodeHash: 'none',
      },
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200,
      },
      outputSelection: {
        '*': {
          '*': [
            'abi',
            'evm.bytecode',
            'evm.deployedBytecode',
            'evm.methodIdentifiers',
            'metadata',
          ],
          '': ['ast'],
        },
      },
      evmVersion: "paris",
    },
    compilers: [
      {
        version: "0.8.10"
      }
    ]
  },

